# Setting background color to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, background-color, frameset

Ok, so I'm very new to Javascript and I was wondering how one goes about making the background color a variable. Specifically, I have three different frames, and I want two of the ones on the side to change their color based on which page is being visited in the third frame. How can I set the background color to for these two side frames to a variable that can be changed by whatever document is in the third frame? I've been looking around online but my search has been fruitless.

EDIT-
Alternately, a way to change it by clicking on a hyperlink would work just as well for my purposes.

EDIT 2 -
In the same vein as the last question, this is an alternate approach I'm trying that isn't producing much luck either, though I have more information about it:
[Setting background color to variable in javascript Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643686/setting-background-color-to-variable-in-javascript-part-2)

Comment: You should edit this question, instead of posting a new one if you are just including more information.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate the background color property with javascript you need to:

```
//Set to red
document.getElementById("frame").style.backgroundColor="red"; 

//Save into variable
var color = document.getElementById("frame").style.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm implementing that incorrectly, since that doesn't seem to be working. I've put those in the third frame within the head and within script tags, though perhaps I should leave those tags out?

Comment: <HEAD>
<TITLE>Webcomics Review</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
documentGetElementById("Head").style.backgroundColor="red";
var color=documentGetElementById("Head").style.backgroundColor;
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

Comment: That would be in the relevant portion of the script in the third frame, with "Head" being the name of the frame I'm trying to manipulate.

Comment: and frame has the id="Head" right?, try using window.onload=function(){ documentGetElementById("Head").style.backgroundColor="red"; }

Comment: Ok, the current code within the head of frame 3 is <SCRIPT>
window.onload=function()
{
 documentGetElementById("Head").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
documentGetElementById("Head").style.backgroundColor="red";
var color=documentGetElementById("Head").style.backgroundColor;
</SCRIPT> though that isn't working either, so I'm assuming I've placed this either in the wrong place within the code or that it's in the wrong order.

Comment: I've also tried using only the function, and that didn't help either. Alternately, how it could be done with an onClick event associated with a hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var frameRef = document.getElementById("frameId");
//alternatively  you can get all farmes in one array
//var textRef = document.querySelectorAll(".frameClass");

function changeBg(newColor){
  frameRef.style.backgroundColor =  newColor;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeBg('red')" value="red">Red</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeBg('blue')" value="blue">Blue</button>
```