# Setting background color to variable in javascript Part 2

Tags: javascript, background-color, frameset

I'm very new to JavaScript, and I have a webpage with 3 nested frames (a top one, and then a bottom one divided into two.) The top frame is titled Head, the bottom-left one is titled LeftFrame and the final one is titled RightFrame. Now, LeftFrame is a navigation bar, and I want to make it so that clicking on a link in LeftFrame will change the background color of Head.
This is the code for the main webpage:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Webcomics Review</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<FRAMESET BORDER=0 ROWS="12%,*">
<FRAME NAME"Head" NORESIZE SRC="Head.html">

<FRAMESET BORDER=0 COLS="15%,*">
<FRAME NAME="LeftFrame" NORESIZE SRC="navigation.html">
<FRAME NAME="RightFrame" NORESIZE SRC="mainpage.html">
</FRAMESET>

</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

And this is the code for the navigation bar which just has one link being worked on so far as a test:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Webcomics Review</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
function setColor1(number)
{
    if (number==1)
    {
        parent.Head.document.body.style.backgroundColor=#FF0000;
    }
    return;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<FONT SIZE=3 FACE=Haettenschweiler>Webcomics:
<BR><BR>
<A HREF="xkcd.html" TARGET="RightFrame" STYLE="text-decoration: none" onClick="setColor1(1)">Xkcd</A>
<BR><BR>
<A HREF="qc.html" TARGET="RightFrame" STYLE="text-decoration: none">Questionable Content</A>
<BR><BR>
<A HREF="qwantz.html" TARGET="RightFrame" STYLE="text-decoration: none">Dinosaur Comics</A>
<BR><BR>
<A HREF="survivingtheworld.html" TARGET="RightFrame" STYLE="text-decoration: none">Surviving the World</A>
<BR><BR>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong, as nothing about the Head frame changes when upon clicking the "xkcd" link in navigation (the one I'm using to test.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting background color to variable in javascript.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643374/setting-background-color-to-variable-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//MAIN FRAMES PAGE
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColor1(color)
{
    HEAD.document.body.style.backgroundColor=color;
    return;
}
window.setColor = function(a){setColor1(a);}
</script>
</head>
<FRAMESET BORDER=1 ROWS="12%,*">
<FRAME NAME="HEAD" NORESIZE SRC="frame_head.html" id="HEAD">
<FRAMESET BORDER=1 COLS="15%,*">
    <FRAME NAME="LeftFrame" NORESIZE SRC="frame_footer.html">
    <FRAME NAME="RightFrame" NORESIZE SRC="frame_body.html">
</FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
</html>
//END MAIN FRAMES PAGE
/**************************************************************************/
//BODY PAGE (RightFrame)
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColor(color)
{
    window.parent.setColor(color);
    return;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="setColor('#f00')">one</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="setColor('#0f0')">two</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="setColor('#00f')">three</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="setColor('#f0f')">four</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="setColor('#ff0')">five</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="setColor('#0ff')">six</a>&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
/**************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Ok, that's working well for changing the frame it's in, but changing the target from "document.body.style.backgroundColor" to "parent.Head.body.style.backgroundColor" doesn't work for changing the Head frame, nor does moving that function to the Head frame itself. Any recommendations for that?

Comment: I'm not getting your updated answer to work, I made it as a separate webpage instead of trying to implement it into the one I already have. I have the left frame and head frame as blank HTML documents with the bodypage saved onto the right frame, but nothing is happening when I click on the numbers.

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain a bit what that segment Javascript is accomplishing and why it's placed where it is I could figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: @Jon in Body Page we are calling `setcolor` function of the container page (where we have defined frames), I think this is simple. In container page we have defined function named `setColor1` and then bound it with `window.setColor = function(a){setColor1(a);};` So when we call `window.parent.setColor(color);` it is transfered to `setColor1(a);` in container frame.

Comment: Alright. Me and a friend have been working on this and we got it to the point where the exact same code works for him but not for me, using function setColor(color)
{
        frames["Head"].document.body.style.backgroundColor=color;
        frames["LeftFrame"].document.body.style.backgroundColor=color;
        return;
}